# Infer associations/validations from existing database in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does Magic Model Generator work under Rails 3.0? I can't make it work, the install instructions that I found, doesn't help me.

Does exist an alternative to Magic Model Generator that can infer validations and associations from an existing database?

Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the MMG is abandoned -- it doesn't even work for Rails 2.3. However -- you could create a Rails 2.2 app and use it with MMG, then use the models in your Rails 3 app.

http://github.com/drnic/magic_model_generator